# Why type is referred in case of method overriding?

Tags: java, exception, overriding

I have understanding that  in case of method overriding **Object** is checked instead of **Type**

```
class SuperException extends Exception {}
class SubException extends SuperException {}

class AnotherException extends Exception {}
class YetAnotherException extends Exception {}

class A {
  void play() throws SuperException, AnotherException {}
}
class Reduced extends A {
  void play() throws SuperException {} 
}
class Eliminated extends A {
  void play() {} 
}
class Narrower extends A {
  void play() throws SubException {}
}
class TestPolymorphism {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A obj = new Eliminated();
    obj.play();                         // Doubt 1
    Eliminated eobj = new Eliminated(); // Doubt 2
  }
}
```

Doubt 1: Why play() is referred from class A?

Doubt 2: Why compilation error?

Comment: If you're asking about compilation errors, you should actually include them in your question.

Answer (score 1):

1. obj is of Eliminated type which extends A, therefore it can be referred by a variable of type A.
2. The compilation error is in obj.play(), because you don't catch the exception it throws. Since obj is declared to be of type A, the compiler expects that you handle the 2 types of exceptions it may throw. It doesn't know that in practice these exceptions are never thrown. If you declared obj as Eliminated, then the error would disappear.

Comment: I get compilation error for Eliminated eobj = new Eliminated(); but not for Reduced red = new Reduced();      , What could be the reason??

Comment: @SibaPrasadPatro: ok, I see the error message in another comment. It looks like the code you posted is not the same as the code you get the error for. If all your classes are defined outside of the scope of TestPolymorphism (just as in the code you posted), this shouldn't appear. If your classes are nested, define them as static.

Comment: Thanks Eyal , I had done some manipulations and hence the error occurred . Making the class static, sorted out the problems .

Answer (score 1):

Answer to Doubt 1 : As you have reference of type A, compiler refers to the method of type reference i.e play() method of class A. It is resolved to actual one at runtime i.e. it is of class Eliminated.

Doubt 2 : Play method throws an checked exception, and hence it needs to behandles by the calling method. Here play() method of A class is referred which throws the Exception, hence it should be handled.

Comment: Ankur, Thanks for clarifying the Doubt 1

Comment: In Doubt 2 , my question is I get compilation error  in case of Eliminated eobj = new Eliminated(); but not in case of Reduced red = new Reduced();

Comment: Can you paste the error message in the comment. I think the error is due to checked exception not handled for the play() method in previous line itself.

Comment: No enclosing instance of type TestPolymorphism is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type TestPolymorphism (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of TestPolymorphism).

Comment: Thanks Ankur . There was some manipulations done in the source and hence the error occurred .

Comment: You are welcome @SibaPrasadPatro. Even I was trying to figure out why was it failing. Anyways good that you figured it out on your own :-)

Answer (score 1):

A is the super class, so can refer to sub class object of any level. It will call the method of class 'Eliminated' that you provided.

update the line
from
public static void main(String[] args) to
public static void main(String[] args) throws SuperException, AnotherException
will eliminate the exception, since the exception is thrown by play method itself. or you have to have try catch in main method, since it is checked exception, checked by compiler at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

[Run-Time Evaluation of Method Invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4)

> At run time, method invocation requires five steps. First, a target
>   reference may be computed. Second, the argument expressions are
>   evaluated. Third, the accessibility of the method to be invoked is
>   checked. Fourth, the actual code for the method to be executed is
>   located. Fifth, a new activation frame is created, synchronization is
>   performed if necessary, and control is transferred to the method code.